# Mem leak in program? C

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

dynamically allocated an array of cstrings to delimit the string passed it. Valgrind says I have a a 7 allocs but only 3 frees. But I am unsure how to free memory while using a function that returns an array.

here is the function

```
char ** func( char * str, char del ) {
     char** substrings;
     char* word;
     int len = 0, capacity = 2, i, x;
     substrings = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (capacity + 1));
     for (i = 0; i <= capacity; i++){
         substrings[i] = NULL;
     }
     while (*word != '\0') {
         if (len  >= capacity){
             /* double size */
             char **temp;
             capacity *= 2;
             temp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (capacity + 1));
             for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                 temp[i] = substrings[i];
             }
             for (i = len; i <= capacity; i++) {
                 temp[i] = NULL;
             }
             substrings = temp;

             temp = NULL;
             free(temp);

         }
     }     
     return substrings;
 }
```

Comment: You should probably learn about [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Comment: And until you change your code to use [`realloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc), take moment and think about these two statements: `temp = NULL; free(temp);`

Comment: Is it not possible to do it with `malloc`?

Comment: Of course it's possible, but it's *much* simpler with a `realloc` call which handles the allocation of the extra memory *and* the copying *and* the freeing of the old memory all in one single function call. So you can go from ten lines to one, and don't worry about making a mistake like you have.

Comment: The rule is simple: For each value returned by `malloc(...)/calloc(...)/realloc(NULL, ...) /strdup(...) `there needs to be exactly one call to `free()` passing this very value.

Comment: How do you know how many entries are in the array returned by `stuStrTok`?  Most of the time, there'll be a NULL pointer to mark the end, but I think you can end up without one.  Have you learned about structures yet?  If so, consider using one to encapsulate the amount of space allocated, the amount of space used, and the actual array of strings.  This will make it easier to pass the array around.

Comment: regarding this line: `while (*word != '\0') `   The first time through the loop, the `word` pointer is not initialized.  Dereferencing that pointer is undefined behavior and can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: regarding this line: `if (len  >= capacity){` the first time through, `len` is 0 and `capacity` is 2, so the body of the `if` code block is never entered, so those values will never change.

Comment: the pointer `word` is never updated within the `while()` loop, so if the execution ever enters that loop, it will never exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

From your code,

```
if (len  >= capacity){
         /* double size */
         char **temp;
         capacity *= 2;
         temp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * (capacity + 1));
         for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
             temp[i] = substrings[i];
         }
         for (i = len; i <= capacity; i++) {
             temp[i] = NULL;
         }
         free(substrings); // release old memory
         substrings = temp; // this line causes substrings pointer leak if you assign new address to it without free

         temp = NULL;
         free(temp); // no need free NULL

     }
```

Actually, if you use the **valgrind** with *--track-origins=yes* option, it will report which the line is leaking.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.
1) I assume the program you have given is not the one you are using in your application. I see multiple issues like, `word` is not initialized.

2) As others pointed out, the issue is because you are assigning NULL to a pointer and then freeing it.

From the code it looks like you are trying to do the following.

```
         for (i = len; i <= capacity; i++) {
             /* Your code */
         }

         /* Free the previous substring. */
         if(NULL != substrings){
             free(substrings);
         }

         /* Save newly allocated temp as substring. */
         substrings = temp;

         /* Clear temp variable - Optional. */
         temp = NULL;
```